# Alternatives to $templateCache in Angular2

Tags: angular

When we think of using `template` in Angular2 or Angular1.X, we know below is one of the basic way of writing:

`template: './template-ninja.html'`

and with Angular1.X, we can previously cache all of templates with `$templateCache.put()` as follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module('Ninja', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateNinja.html', 'This is the content of the template-ninja');
});
```

which will lessen the number of http requests.
I'd like to know how can I implement the same with Angular2. Could anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### gulp-inline-ng2-template

Currently the best solution is gulp-inline-ng2-template.

This takes a component with a templateUrl attribute, plus an html file, and turns it into a component with an inlined template.

https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a library or tool that will cache templates for Angular 2 yet, but so far, I have been happy to just use inline templates instead of external files. Using the es6 backtick character for a template, it allows you to write multiline HTML in the JavaScript and keeps everything in one file.

https://github.com/angular-in-action/chapter2/blob/master/client/components/dashboard.ts#L12

Answer (score 2):

Use the following alternative:

- Import RuntimeCompiler, reflector, ComponentFactory, ComponentResolver, ReflectorComponentResolver, and ReflectionInfo
- Inject RuntimeCompiler
- Create a ComponentResolver instance
- Invoke ComponentResolver.resolveComponent(SomeComponent)
- Check reflector.propMetadata for the cached result

```
    it('should cache the result', inject([AsyncTestCompleter], (async) => {
         PromiseWrapper
             .all([ComponentResolver.resolveComponent(SomeComponent), ComponentResolver.resolveComponent(SomeComponent)])
             .then((protoViewRefs) => {
               expect(protoViewRefs[0]).toBe(protoViewRefs[1]);
               async.done();
             });
       }));
```

Annotation is the other way to do it:

```
    it('should read the template from an annotation',
       inject([AsyncTestCompleter, Compiler], (async, compiler) => {
         ComponentResolver.resolveComponent(SomeComponent)
             .then((hostViewFactoryRef) => {
               expect(hostViewFactoryRef.internalHostViewFactory).toBe(someHostViewFactory);
               async.done();
             });
       }));
```

**References**

- [Angular2 Source: RuntimeCompiler Spec - runtime_compiler_spec.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.ts)
- [Angular2 API: ProtoViewRef Class](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ProtoViewRef-class.html)
- [Angular2 Source: Public API Specs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/tools/public_api_guard/public_api_spec.ts)
- [npm modules: ng2cli - CLI util to generate Angular 2 files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2cli)
- [Angular2 Issue #6317, Feature offer: some annotation inside templates to indicate the interface they require.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6317)

Answer (score 2):

**gulp-ng2-template-wrap**

Hi,

Hope this will be helpful to you: I just wrote a small module that allows you to bundle all of your html files into single ES6 module.

https://github.com/evgenys91/gulp-ng2-template-wrap