# $templateCache in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

In Angular 1, we use the $templateCache as a way to avoid XHR'ing down every template from the server as we bootstrap our app. In Angular 2, there doesn't appear to be such a mechanism ready-built.

What I can do is replace XHR in the compiler:

```
function myXhr() {};
myXhr.prototype.get = function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            method:'GET',
            success:resolve,
            error:reject
        });
    });
};

ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(MyApp, [
    ng.core.provide(ng.compiler.XHR, {useClass:myXhr})
]);
```

And then adjust my XHR getter to check a local cache first. Is this the preferred approach?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418914/alternatives-to-templatecache-in-angular2, although asked on the same day and as of yet without solution.

Comment: Still no good solution for this, just a lot of handwaving.

Answer (score 3):

I have become accustomed to using template strings in typescript for all my components. I find having the html and view logic all in one TS file very convenient.
You could also look into a module loader/bundler like [JSPM](http://jspm.io) or [WebPack](https://webpack.github.io/). These great build tools pull in all your templates into your builds using module syntax like below:

```
let html = require('./about.html!text');
    @Component({
        selector:"my-about",
        template:html
    })
```

Comment: Just what I am looking for, and I don't need to use absolute paths to templates. Now if only there is a way to translate this into es6 import syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'text', which one to install?

Answer (score 2):

The cache in Angular2 works as follows:

- app layer: method on `ViewContainerRef` is called (e.g. `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`).
- `reflector.registerType` registers the component type as an annotation
- `ComponentResolver.resolveComponent` now returns a `ComponentFactory`
- `ComponentResolver.resolveComponent` first checks the type annotations before returning a Promise

Initial design in Angular 2.0 Alpha:

> A ProtoView is a prototypical View that is the result of Template compilation and is used by Angular to efficiently create an instance of this View based on the compiled Template.
>
> RenderProtoViewRef is a counterpart to ProtoViewRef available in the Application Context. But unlike ProtoViewRef, RenderProtoViewRef contains all static nested Proto Views that are recursively merged into a single Render Proto View.
>
> It is no longer possible to implement ng-include. The compiler requires a ComponentDirective in order to compile HTML. Therefore, you cannot compile HTML on its own and include it into a View.

Relevant changes since the initial Angular 2.0 Beta:

> Compiler is renamed to ComponentResolver, Compiler.compileInHost has been renamed to ComponentResolver.resolveComponent.
>
> Renderer interface now operates on plain native nodes, instead of RenderElementRefs or RenderViewRefs
>
> AppViewManager is renamed into ViewUtils and is a mere private utility service.

**References**

- [Angular2 Rendering Architecture](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M9FmT05Q6qpsjgvH1XvCm840yn2eWEg0PMskSQz7k4E/mobilebasic?pli=1)
- [Angular2 Issue #2604: Compiler.compileInHost should first check the cache before creating `DirectiveBinding`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2604)
- [Angular2 Tests: Entry Components Integration Spec](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/packages/core/test/linker/entry_components_integration_spec.ts)
- [Angular2 Tests: Reflector Spec](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/packages/core/test/reflection/reflector_spec.ts)
- [Angular2 Pull Request #7762: Resolvers now use DI to create Reflector](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7762)
- [Angular2 Changelog: 2.0.0-beta.1 - Breaking Changes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)
- [All About Angular 2.0](http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/all-about-angular-2-0/)