# How to use CachedResourceLoader as an equivalent mechanism to $templateCache in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-templatecache

I know there are [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421869/templatecache-in-angular-2) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418914/alternatives-to-templatecache-in-angular2) questions about this but with no solution for any of them.

So I found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6612) issue in Angular repo where they ask for the same, i.e an alternative for templateCache in Angular 2 but they close it saying you can use CachedResourceLoader.

So my question is **how to use this CachedResourceLoader to replace the templateCache**, I have been searching on google about this but couldn't find any related content so maybe I am not pointing to the right direction or I missed something.

The answer to this question could be a valid answer for the other 2 similar questions.

Code example for the functionality that templateCache provided in AngularJS:

**Adding**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

**Retrieval** via $templateCache:

```
$templateCache.get('templateId.html')
```

Or retrieval:

```
myApp.component('myComponent', {
   templateUrl: 'templateId.html'
});
```

Comment: The question doesn't specify how exactly you intend to use it.

Comment: I want to have the same functionality for angular 2 than templateCache provided for angular 1. i.e The first time a template is used, it is loaded in the template cache for quick retrieval. You can load templates directly into the cache in a script tag, or by consuming the $templateCache service directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`CachedResourceLoader`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.3/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_cache.ts) is existing yet undocumented Angular 2+ substitution for AngularJS `$templateCache`:

> An implementation of ResourceLoader that uses a template cache to
>   avoid doing an actual ResourceLoader.
>
> The template cache
>   needs to be built and loaded into window.$templateCache via a
>   separate mechanism.

It is supposed to work by providing `ResourceLoader` provider:

```
{provide: ResourceLoader, useClass: CachedResourceLoader}
```

Which was already defined in existing [`RESOURCE_CACHE_PROVIDER`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic/RESOURCE_CACHE_PROVIDER) export.

And `window.$templateCache` is supposed to contain pairs of URLs and responses.

Since `ResourceLoader` should be specified before compilation, it should be provided not in application module but in compiler options.

Here is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/j69lNUcL6xFDkqsUXB82?p=preview):

```
import {RESOURCE_CACHE_PROVIDER} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {COMPILER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/core';

window['$templateCache'] = { 'app.html': `...`};

platformBrowserDynamic({
  provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS,
  useValue: { providers: [RESOURCE_CACHE_PROVIDER] },
  multi: true
}).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

As opposed to AngularJS `$templateCache`, `CachedResourceLoader` doesn't allow to make requests for missing templates. This is desirable behaviour most of the time. If it has to be changed, a custom implementation that extends default [`ResourceLoader` implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.3/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.ts) can be used instead.