# Choosing framework with needed level of flexibility

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, vue.js, frameworks

I am trying to select framework, which replace our old framework 
( middle-sized project )

Our previous project was written with angularJS, so our team write core of this application and distribute it to our clients, some of them has their own frontend teams and they can easily customize core components/controllers via $templateCache mechanism

like so:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

so these "outsource teams" can fully redefine components ( i mean not only css but layout too )

and include their "custom" components via custom.js files

I am looking for information how we can do same thing.

It looks like using React render props is not suitable for us, because we must have ability to replace any component in runtume just add *.js file

but i'm pretty new in Angular2+ and Vue did these frameworks has such mechanisms?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418914/alternatives-to-templatecache-in-angular2

Comment: @PavelB. Great! Thanks i'll read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js has a pretty well-structured way for components. You can have the html, css and javascript all managed in one place. For basic examples, see the official documentation at [vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Once having written the components, it's kind of intuitive to use and reuse them in our main html file.
Feel free to try it out!

Also, vue is a modular framework, meaning you don't have to use it's own routing system etc. for getting started with it's template engine. It could even run along side other frameworks.